# Spark job on Mesos not working when submitting job via mesos dispatcher

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I have had spark running on Standalone Cluster Manager, and I decided to try out Mesos.

When I am using client mode, everything works working perfectly.
If I want to run in cluster mode, I realized I had to start "mesos cluster dispatcher". 
I tried starting it with regular script:

> ./start-mesos-dispatcher mesos://ip:5050

as well as using directions from the following link

http://www.simosh.com/article/dbcjefbf-start-spark-via-mesos.html

but cluster mode did not work in both cases. In both of them, I saw in Mesos UI that driver is submitted, but after several seconds it gets killed.

After that I tried to submit job to mesos in client mode, using dispatcher again, and I saw that submitting process stucks in following step:

> I0509 11:09:44.550375  3339 sched.cpp:326] New master detected at master@127.0.1.1:7078
>   I0509 11:09:44.555305  3339 sched.cpp:336] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication

In spark logs, I saw that dispatcher is correctly started, and I see framework is registered in Mesos UI.

Are there some settings that I am missing?